# Microphone doesn't work

Tags: sound, chromium, vlc, microphone

Dell Inspiron series 15 (3552), came with ubuntu 14.04, upgraded to ubuntu 16.04. The build-in microphone doesn't seem to be recording sound.

I tried video-chatting with my daughter via facebook -using Chromium - but we noticed that from my machine, audio didn't pass. Testing with Firefox and another camera worked, only once, because selecting a different camera/audio input is not easy (fb, Chromium/Firefox)

Using VLC as capture program, I was able to determine that the microphone next to the screen-camera doesn't record sound, but is it really a hardware problem, or is it a 'settings', or driver problem?

When seleccting the devices for recording (VLC), I use /dev/video0, and for audio, my only choice is hw:0,0 Now, is thàt correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with settings.

I'm on Xubuntu so I'm flying blind here as far as locations and exact names of stuff is, but you can try:

From the launcher go to System-Settings -> Sound. You should get a dialogue with a number of tabs that read "Output", "Input", and so on. Select the "Input" one and you should get a drop-down menu with a selection of devices or ports. Try them out one by one, testing the microphone until you get the right setting.

Answer (score 0):

Went to Settings, Sound. 
Tab 'Input' shows: Internal Microphone *Buit-in Audio*.
That setting was [v] Mute, I did unselecct it.
The input level below that, now shows reaction when I tap the microphone, next to camera on the screen edge.
But still VLC records no audio.
  When I select both /dev/video0 for input video, and hw:0,0 for input audio, I get this messagefrom VLC (pop-up window): 
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'alsa://hw:0,0'. Check the log for details.
Selected or not, no sound is recorded.